# passing form values from one jsp to another

Tags: jsp

i need to access form data given entered in one jsp in another.. 
this is how my code looks
fisrt jsp:

```
<form name="register" action="enterRegDetails.jsp" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="" size=25/>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
```

second jsp:

```
 <%=request.getParameter("firstame")%>
```

now this prints a null value..

what is the mistake here?
how do i get to access the values in my second jsp?

Comment: You would normally use EL to display values, not *scriptlets*. The above scriptlet can be replaced by `${param.firstname}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 name="firstname"

 <%=request.getParameter("firstame")%>
```

It is not just the spelling mistake, is it? (Missing n)

Comment: oh gosh! i was boggling my head over a spelling mistake all this while!!!!! thanks thilo :)

Comment: what are you coding in?  eclipse would have pointed this out to you pretty quickly

Comment: Sorry mis-read... shouldn't have been posting after my bed time :)