# Is it possible to pass an arraylist from one JSP page to another without using session

Tags: jsp, session, arraylist

I am trying to pass an `ArrayList` from a JSP page to another JSP page.
Is it possible to do without using session?
please reply...

`one.jsp`:

```
<%
     testActions reqact = new testActions(Con);
    reqact.getAllRecordsforAll();//Getting data from DB and stores it on an Arraylist contains test object array
    ArrayList<test> list1 = new ArrayList<test>();
    list1=reqact.ListOfObjects//assigning the resulting list to list1
%>
```

On a button click event from `one.jsp` I want to load `two.jsp` and also wanto access the same list (`list1`) in `two.jsp`.

I want to avoid the usage of session so is there any other way available?

Comment: Sure, it's possible.  Show us your code and we might be able to help.

Comment: @Tap I have added a sample code. Please go through it.

Comment: You might be able to use Javascript to preserve context between jsp pages.  You can also use a query string, or hidden form fields.  Q: *What's wrong with a session*?  What requirement do you have that prevents "doing it the right way"?

Comment: It looks like you're already persisting the list to your database.  Why not do the same thing on two.jsp that you're doing on one.jsp?  If the list isn't changing, and the query is not super expensive, I think that's the simplest solution.  You'll be dealing with different java objects, but the same data.

Comment: @tap I dont know how to explain the actual thing i want and why i need it. It is too messy to put my entire code here to explain the thing . What i put here is just a model of my code.. and not all of it. Any way thanks for your concern. I actually was expecting an answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to carry the data in some scope (session or request).

Check this question for [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542512/passing-form-values-from-one-jsp-to-another)

Comment: I want a solution which avoids the usage of session

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on what do you mean by "pass from one JSP to another".

Are you including one JSP into another? You can set parameters in `<jsp:include>`. 
Are you forwarding from one JSP to another `<jsp:forward>`? You can use parameters too :-) Another option is to store the list into request or page scope using JSTL's `<c:set>` tag.